# How to mock a React Native native module"in Jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-native-module

I want something like the following (that actually works...):

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import PushNotifications from '../../app/platform/PushNotificationSupport';


const mockRNA = jest.requireMock('react-native');
jest.mock('react-native', () => {
    return {
        default: mockRNA.default,
        NativeModules: {
            ...mockRNA.NativeModules,
            NativePushNotifications: {
                setTokenHandler: jest.fn(),
            },
        },
    };
});
```

Of course, the above code doesn't actually work. I essentially want to build on top of the existing `react-native` mock.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mock `NativeModules` directly

```
jest.mock('NativeModules', () => ({
    NativePushNotifications: {
        setTokenHandler: jest.fn(),
    },
    ...
}));
```